# SendKeys {SUBTRACT} not working

Tags: c#, sendkeys, uat

I've searched the Internet and this web site for any clues to fix my issue, but haven't found one.
I have a method that expects a string and then does `SendKeys.SendWait(str)`. **Everything** works like passing in `"{ENTER}"` or just typing normal text.

**But**! If I pass in `"{SUBTRACT}"` it just doesn't work. I've also tried passing in the ASCII presentation of the key, but it threw exception that its unsupported.

I've also tried just doing `SendKeys.Send("{SUBTRACT}")` - no results what so ever.

Its just not doing anything. However, when I press the minus button on the keypad or on the top of the keyboard - functionality works.

Please note that this is using windows Automation Framework. May be this is what causing the problem. Has anyone had the same issues?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Alina. Can you post your code where u have execute `SendKeys.Send("{SUBSTRACT}")` statement? So, we can debug it.

Comment: Hi, thanks! But this is all what it does really. I have my own application - not an external one. And there's a ultraGrid that accepts the - and + keys to expand/collapse the rows. All my automation is doing - is it selects a row and then uses SendKeys.SendWait("{SUBTRACT}"); to hopefully expand the row. But it's just not doing it at all

Comment: So, you want to expand grid node on **Subtract** key down event? I have tried `SendKeys.Send("{SUBTRACT}")` statement. I have executed this line on button click and i got `-` written in my `Textbox`. So, it was working in my case. let me try to handle `Subtract KeyDown` event and call any specific method on it.

Comment: Is this windows application?

Comment: Try using it on an ultraGrid and see if you see the same issue. May be it's the ultraGrid control. And really appreciate your helping!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to show messagebox on `Subtract KeyDown` event. I have sent `Subtract` key on my button click event. **But, make sure you have enabled `KeyPreview` property of your windows form.**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendKeys.Send("{SUBTRACT}");
}

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Subtract)
        this.UltraGrid1.Rows.CollapseAll(true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much! That worked! I still wonder though why the individual row expansion wasn't working for me. But that's alright :) definitely a solve :) Thank you!